# Переменная в названии кнопки Python PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyside2, variable

Есть кнопки: `Button0`, `Button1`, `Button2` и  `Button3`
и переменная `f`.

При нажатии на кнопку `Button0`:

```
global f
f = 0

def Button0_clicked(self):
        f + 1
        btn = "Button" 
        btnname = btn + str(f)
        self.ui.btnname.show()
        self.ui.btnname.settext('settext')
```

Выводит ошибку -

> AttributeError: 'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'btnname'

Как сделать так, чтобы он считал `btnname` переменной, а не именем кнопки
(или же есть другой вариант как это сделать)

весь код:

```
import sys
import os
import re
from PyQt5 import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(747, 398)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.Button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Button1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 80, 75, 23))
        self.Button1.setObjectName("Button1")
        self.Button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Button2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 80, 75, 23))
        self.Button2.setObjectName("Button2")
        self.Button3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Button3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 80, 75, 23))
        self.Button3.setObjectName("Button3")
        self.Button0 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Button0.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 40, 75, 23))
        self.Button0.setObjectName("Button0")
        self.Button1.hide()
        self.Button2.hide()
        self.Button3.hide()

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.action = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action.setObjectName("action")

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Pr"))
        self.Button1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.Button2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.Button3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        self.Button0.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить"))


class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.Button1.clicked.connect(self.Button1_clicked)
        self.ui.Button2.clicked.connect(self.Button2_clicked)
        self.ui.Button3.clicked.connect(self.Button3_clicked)
        self.ui.Button0.clicked.connect(self.Button0_clicked)
        global f
        f = 0

    def Button0_clicked(self):
        f + 1
        btn = "Button"
        btnname = btn + str(f)
        self.ui.btnname.show()
        self.ui.btnname.settext('settext')

    def Button1_clicked(self):
        null()

    def Button2_clicked(self):
        null()

    def Button3_clicked(self):
        null()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: что должно произойти при нажатии на кнопку "Добавить" ?

Comment: Должна показаться первая кнопка при втором нажатии вторая и т.д.

Comment: создайте список кнопок и дергайте нужную по индексу f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
#import os
#import re
#from PyQt5 import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(747, 398)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.Button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Button1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 80, 75, 23))
        self.Button1.setObjectName("Button1")
        self.Button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Button2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 80, 75, 23))
        self.Button2.setObjectName("Button2")
        self.Button3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Button3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 80, 75, 23))
        self.Button3.setObjectName("Button3")

        self.Button0 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Button0.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 40, 75, 23))
        self.Button0.setObjectName("Button0")

#        self.Button1.hide()
#        self.Button2.hide()
#        self.Button3.hide()

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.action = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action.setObjectName("action")

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Pr"))
        self.Button1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.Button2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.Button3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        self.Button0.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить"))



class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.Button1.hide()
        self.ui.Button2.hide()
        self.ui.Button3.hide()       

        self.ui.Button1.clicked.connect(self.Button1_clicked)
        self.ui.Button2.clicked.connect(self.Button2_clicked)
        self.ui.Button3.clicked.connect(self.Button3_clicked)
        self.ui.Button0.clicked.connect(self.Button0_clicked)

#        global f                                                          # ---

        self.f = 0                                                         # +++

        setattr(self, "Button1", self.ui.Button1)                          # +++
        setattr(self, "Button2", self.ui.Button2)                          # +++
        setattr(self, "Button3", self.ui.Button3)                          # +++

# ++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv 
    def Button0_clicked(self):
        self.f += 1
        if self.f > 3:
            return
        obj = getattr(self, "Button{}".format(self.f))  
        obj.show()
        obj.setText(f'settext - {self.f}')
# ++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        

    def Button1_clicked(self):
        print(f'def Button1_clicked(self):')

    def Button2_clicked(self):
        print(f'def Button2_clicked(self):')

    def Button3_clicked(self):
        print(f'def Button3_clicked(self):')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]